# CA Root Certificate and Domain/Intermediate certificate

Tags: certificate

I have made CA Root certificate with "New-SelfSignedCertificateEx".
My problem is how to create domain/server/intermediate certificate which is slave to root?

Can you help me?

I have made CA Root Authority certificate. I use power shell instead makecert.exe command. I added into my trusted zone.

Now I want to create server CN=domain certificate which is extend CA authority.  I need to sign and deploy on my IIS. How to do that with ps1 language?

|-----"My ROOT CA" 
            |
            |--------"My Slave" (DNS CN=domain.local)

I thing I need to set "Issued to" and "Issued by".

"My ROOT CA" 
   Issued to - My ROOT CA
   Issued by - My ROOT CA

"My Slave" 
   Issued to - My ROOT CA
   Issued by - domain.local